# Monte Carlo Integration Optimization

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x

The code below is my shot at trying to do monte carlo integration of the function sin(x) from 0 to pi in Python 3.
I sample randomly 10000 times a floating number from 0 to pi and do the standard procedure of the monte carlo integration and also take the average of ten results for an even better approximation,i was wondering if there is anything i can do to optimize my code from a time or accuracy standpoint.

```
import random
import math

def func(n):
    return math.sin(n)

integralres=0

for t in range(10):
    resf=0
    for i in range(10000):
        u=random.uniform(0,math.pi)
        resf+=func(u)
    integralres+=(math.pi)*resf/10000

print(integralres/10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Style

[PEP8 is the Python style guide](https://pep8.org/) and is worth a read to keep your code clear and understandable.

### Naming

You're not using your loop indicies, `t` and `i`, it's customary to replace them with `_` to indicate this.

The name `func` for a function doesn't tell you what it does. Names should be as descriptive as possible, in this case `sin` seems sensible

```py
def sin(x):
    return math.sin(x)
```

### Functions

The function `sin` doesn't actually give you anything, as is now clearer, and I'd remove it altogether.

The calculation of you integration *is* discrete, and might be used separately. I would put that inside a function

```py
def monte_carlo(n):
    resf = 0
    for _ in range(n):
        uniform_rand_no = random.uniform(0, math.pi)
        resf += math.sin(uniform_rand_no)
    return math.pi * resf / 10000
```

Note that I've:

1. Allowed you to pick the number of iterations
2. Added spaces around operators

I'm not really sure what `resf` means, otherwise I would have renamed that too.

### Main

All your code will execute when you import your file. If you use the following you can gate execution solely to when the file is run:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    for _ in range(10):
        ...
```

### Everything

Putting all this together you would get:

```py
import random
import math


def monte_carlo(n):
    resf = 0
    for _ in range(n):
        uniform_rand_no = random.uniform(0, math.pi)
        resf += math.sin(uniform_rand_no)
    return math.pi * resf / 10000


if __name__ == "__main__":

    integral = 0
    n = 10000
    
    for _ in range(10):
        integral += math.pi * monte_carlo(n) / n

    print(integral / 10)
```

Comment: `sin = math.sin` is a lot better declaration than explicit function definition

Comment: Wouldn't you just `from math import sin, pi` rather than declaring that @hjpotter92? (I did forget the `math.` in front of `sin`; I've edited the answer to include it.